# Using multiple conditions in an if statement in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am trying to create a complex if statement in C++ that will save me from writing a whole bunch of if statements, I am wondering if this code below actually makes sense or I am overlooking an error.

```
if(input==choice) {
        cout << "Tie!" << endl;
}else if(input=="rock" && choice=="scissors"
     || input=="scissors" && choice=="paper"
     || input="paper" && choice=="rock") {
        cout << input " beats " << choice << ", you win!" << endl;
}else if(input=="rock" && choice=="paper"
    || input=="scissors" && choice=="rock"
    || input=="paper" && choice=="scissors"){
        cout << choice << " beats " << input << ", you lose!" << endl;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

```
"if input is x AND choice is y, OR if...."
```

Basically I'm testing multiple "if-and" conditions so that a single line of code will execute if it hits any of the if-and conditions. The output throws a "no match for 'operator||'" error.

Comment: Nothing inherently wrong with what you're trying to do except I'd try to avoid so many string comparisons if performance matters.

Comment: @Bungles I am just trying to create a simple rock paper scissors game against the computer. I am trying to work on writing for efficient and fluent code so I am trying something new.

Comment: `input="paper"` -> `input=="paper"`, voting to close as a typo.

Comment: What is the difference between input and choice? You may want to come up with better names.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Input is what the user enters. Choice is the computer picking a random number between 1 and 3 which will then set choice's value to either rock, paper, or scissors.

Comment: What line gives this error? Based on @HolyBlackCat’s comment I bet it’s the fifth line here. I would also add parentheses to clarify the operator precedence (the parser will read this correctly, but I had to check to make sure) and based on what Bungles said I’d make an `enum class Choice {ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS};` and use that instead of string comparison.

Comment: @Daniel H: ``throw`` is a keyword, so you should name the enum differently.

Comment: @DanielH My code worked at first with a single comparison, now it does literally nothing. How do you suggest I integrate enumeration into my code?

Comment: @bjhend Oops, fixed

Comment: @sS5H The enums is an optimization (although you might need to do something if either `input` or `choice` is a C-style string instead of a `std::string`. The fix is to replace the singe equals on line 5 with a double equals

Comment: Just write a function that takes `input` and `choice`, does the tests, and returns a code that indicates the result. You'll find that scales much better when you move to Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock.

Comment: Even if valid to mix `&&` and `||`, using extra parents avoid possible confusion.

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo in `input="paper" && choice=="rock")`, but instead of fixing the typo I would suggest you to fix the code. No wonder you made a typo in this giant block of conditions. You have lots of repetion and mixing logic with output. If you spend some lines on includes, you can save some on code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

bool win(const std::string& input, const std::string& choice) {
    static const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> wins = 
            { { "rock", "scissors" },
              { "scissors", "paper"  },
              { "paper", "rock" }
            };
    return std::find(wins.begin(), wins.end(), std::make_pair(input, choice))
        != wins.end();
}

int main() {
    std::string choice = "paper";
    std::string input = "scissors";
    if (win(choice, input)) { std::cout << "you win! \n"; }
    else                    { std::cout << "you lose! \n"; }
}
```

As next step you should eliminate all that strings, eg by using enums as discussed in the comments.

Comment: Creating a vector is WAY over-engineering it. There are a fixed number of choices, so at *least* use a `std::array`, and a direct implementation of `win` as `if (input == "rock") { return choice == "scissors" } else if ...` would be almost as short and much more readable for both the programmer and the compiler.

Comment: Thank you, I don't think I quite understand every part of this code and why it works but it is what I was looking to achieve.

Comment: @DanielH imho using an `std::array` would be over-engeneering. Why insisting on fixed size when it literally doesnt matter? For your second points its probably a matter of taste. Anyhow the code I showed was just meant as starting point for the OP and I hope you agree that it is easier to read than the original

Comment: Look at the OP’s comment right after mine. This code is easier to read, but *only if* you are already familiar enough with the standard library to recognize what it’s doing. If you are new to C++, even if you are familiar with programming in other languages, it is harder to figure out what’s going on even if the set of what beats what is easier to spot in the code.

Comment: @sS5H, The technique is called called _table lookup_, and it's an important tool to keep in your kit.  Table lookup comes in handy when you need to embed _rules_ in a program.  In this case, there are three rules, that are easy to see in the `wins` table, but somewhat harder to see in your giant `if` statement:  They are, "rock" beats "sci", "sci" beats "pap", and "pap" beats "rock".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table

Comment: @DanielH I consider myself a newbie on the standard library and tbh imho if one doesnt know how to use a vector or `std::find` then its time to learn it. There is nothing weird or obscure in the code. If you dont confront beginners with something just because they might not know it, then you dont give them the chance to learn it

Comment: @DanielH btw I really prefer the code (still not saying that it cannot be improved) to your suggestion of using `if (input == "rock") { return choice == "scissors" }` because when I change the conditions (ie add lizard, spock) then I want to type nothing more than those conditions, no `if`, no `return`, no `==` and also no `=` because I made the typo. As mentioned before, it is probably a matter of taste and I am not claiming that my way is any better, just wanted to answer your first comment

Comment: @jameslarge Okay, I will keep that in mind and definitely familiarize myself with table lookups, thanks.